# Which imports i need to do to use Android Webdriver in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to made some tests with selenium api on my android device. I've already did the tests in desktop with success, but i'm facing some troubles to make the same program on android.

I created an android project using eclipse IDE, and did the download of selenium here:

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ (Java Option)

After, i did the download of the selendroid:

http://selendroid.io/

i've tried to include all these .jar files but when i try to create some AndroidDriver object, my IDE dont recognize this type.

My Class:

```js
package com.example.mobile;


import junit.framework.TestCase;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.mobile.*;

public class OneTeste extends TestCase {

  public void testGoogle() throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();
    
    // And now use this to visit Google
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    
    // Find the text input element by its name
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    
    // Enter something to search for
    element.sendKeys("Cheese!");
    
    // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
    element.submit();
    
    // Check the title of the page
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver; have you tried this ? I got it from this thread https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium don't have Android package.

Comment: See this link - http://www.optimusinfo.com/selenium-android-driver-setup-4/. This gives clear instructions on how to setup the project and has worked for me.

Comment: LittlePanda i'm following this tutorial but the download link of librarys is outdated and the new location don't have the Android Driver to download. I'm thinking the problem is the driver version that i have.